# writing nested while loops in racket

Tags: racket

I was trying to use the [while loop package](https://docs.racket-lang.org/dyoo-while-loop/index.html) in racket to write nested loops like so:

```
(define i 0)
(define j 0)
(while (< i 10)
       (while (< j 10) (printf "~a ~a~n" i j) (set! j (+ j 1)))
       (set! i (+ i 1)) )
```

but for some reason the inner loop was only executed once. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the value of `j` at the end of the first series of iterations: it is 10.

Then `i` is incremented by 1 and the inner loop is started again. But now `j` is 10 and the loop is exited immediately!

To correct this problem, simply re-initialize the value of `j` before any execution of the inner loop, for instance:

```
(define i 0)
(define j 0)
(while (< i 10)
       (set! j 0)
       (while (< j 10) (printf "~a ~a~n" i j) (set! j (+ j 1)))
       (set! i (+ i 1)) )
```